# Showing picture after choosing path from html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an example code for showing an image after choosing the path from html form using jquery. Code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Image Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
        <form id="form12" runat="server">
          <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
          <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
        </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

But after choosing the image, there is shown just the path, and I don`t see any picture. Where could be a problem?

Comment: Append your `script` tag inside `body` in the end and try once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the `script` tag before the closing of `body` tag in the end, so that the DOM is loaded completely before your `script` executes.

Here, in your case, when your code is looking for the element, it is not loaded into the `DOM` yet and hence you were not able to get it working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Image Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form12" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  </form>

<script>
 function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why this works better than the OP's original code.

Comment: Here's another idea: Don't post an answer until it's actually a complete answer. SO generally doesn't appreciate a code dump without an explanation. There's nothing wrong with adding to and improving the answer, as long as it's an answer when it gets posted.

Answer (score -2):

you have not specified the path.your image src has "#" sign.

Comment: He is adding src usign javascript